# how can a clicked asp.net button open jQuery dialog and then resume default when Yes is clicked?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-dialog

I've got a jQuery dialog and an asp.net button (Delete). When the delete button is clicked I want the dialog to open a confirm window saying 'Are you sure you want to delete this record?'. When the user clicks yes I'd like to resume the asp.net postback. Here's my code so far:

```
   $("#dialog-delete").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            'Cancel': function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            'Yes': function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
                //__doPostBack('ctl00$cp1$btnDelete','');
            }
        },
        open: function () {
            $(":button:contains('Yes')").addClass("red");
        }
    });
     $("[id*=btnDelete]").live('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#dialog-delete").dialog('open');
     });
```

So I stop the postback with preventDefault the dialog opens and displays the message but I can't get the delete to fire without hardcoding the delete button, which is nasty. Is there anyway I can hold up the click event whilst the dialog displays and call preventDefault on Cancel and resume on Yes?

Comment: You can be done in one line of code using javascript. lbtnDelete.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?');");

Comment: Yes but that's using the browser confirm. We use the jQuery dialog as standard throughout our application, I have to keep it consistent. We haven't had a need so far to 'continue' with a postback in this way other than in one place (and we hardcoded the postback call - which like I said is nasty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the live event type to mouseup instead of click and then use the click event to fire the postback.

```
$("[id*=btnDelete]").live('mouseup', function (e) { ...

...

$("[id*=btnDelete]").click();
```

**Edit (based on comments)**

Another thought, you could stick with the original idea of handling the click event and upon confirmation of the delete call the [.die()](http://api.jquery.com/die/) function to remove the live event handler previously attached, enabling you to call [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and causing a postback.

You can call the .die() function like so:

```
$("#dialog-delete").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {
        'Cancel': function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        'Yes': function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            $("[id*=btnDelete]").die('click');
            $("[id*=btnDelete]").click();
        }
    },
    open: function () {
        $(":button:contains('Yes')").addClass("red");
    }
});

 $("[id*=btnDelete]").live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#dialog-delete").dialog('open');
 });
```

Comment: I'll try it but I have 2 delete buttons at the top and bottom of my grid. I'll simplify it to one button for now. But with 2 buttons will jQuery/javascript throw a rant if it comes back with 2 elements that match my selector and I try to call the click method? It'd be nice to have a more elegent solution so I can determine which button was clicked by passing in the event args to the dialog or something like that. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Ok, mousedown (despite having preventDefault) still fires the postback. :s Going to try mouseup.

Comment: mouseup worked but had to modify my code to select the first button when it returned 2 matching buttons in my selector. Still holding out for a cleaner solution though. Will post my code as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Submit the ASP.NET form when the appropriate button is clicked.

```
...
buttons: {
      'Cancel': function () {
           $(this).dialog('close');
       },
       'Yes': function () {
           $(this).dialog('close');
           $('#aspnetForm').submit();   // you may need to use a different selector based on your form name
       }
   }
```

Comment: submitting the form in that way isn't going to provide the codebehind with the caller, I need to fire the postback (but then I also need the id of the calling item - which is pretty much where my problem lies).

Answer (score 0):

I got this working but I don't like the solution so far. I'd much prefer a cleaner solution where I can capture the event on the button click and pass it into my dialog in some way, if that's possible. So I'm holding out and hoping someone has a better answer. My code that got it working (for now) is:

```
$("#dialog-delete").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {
        'Cancel': function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        'Yes': function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            $("[id*=btnDelete]")[0].click();
            //__doPostBack('ctl00$cp1$btnVoid','');
        }
    },
    open: function () {
        $(":button:contains('Yes')").addClass("red");
    }
});
 $("[id*=btnDelete]").live('mousedown', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#dialog-delete").dialog('open');
 });
```

Based on the help from @jdavies above (and my comments to enhance the answer). I changed my button handler to a mousedown event and fired the click event in the Yes button handler.

I'm wondering what will happen if the user fires the button via the keyboard, which is part of the reason this feels icky to me. :)

Holding out for something better but it's running at least...

Comment: I've switched from using ASP.NET WebForms because of issues like this.  I always found to get full control of the user experience it required a lot of messy code.  You probably shouldn't have 2 controls with the same ID (btnDelete).  I would them btnDeleteTop & btnDeleteBottom or something.  If you want you can handle keydown and check for the ENTER key and what control has focus but that gets messy fast.  Good luck!

Comment: They are named btnDeleteTop & btnDeleteBottom, the jQuery selector I use is a catch for both, which works. I'm using MVC also at home for my projects and the company I am working for are slowly looking at using it but I'm stuck in asp.net 2 (delphi) with webforms at the moment. :(